# About executing external processes

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I have some external exe that I need to run, and read both its output and errors.

```
            prc = new Process();
            prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            prc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
            prc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            prc.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
            prc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            prc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            prc.OutputDataReceived += (sendingProcess, outLine) => outputText.AppendLine(outLine.Data);
            prc.ErrorDataReceived += (sendingProcess, errorLine) => errorText.AppendLine(errorLine.Data);
            prc.Start();
            prc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            prc.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Thread where this happens may get aborted at any time and there is nothing I can change about it, so I can't use `prc.WaitForExit();` as it can't be aborted until process itself is killed.
That means that every time thread gets aborted, all execution just hangs up.

So I replaced it with this in separate method:

```
while (!Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState.HasFlag(ThreadState.AbortRequested) && !Thread.CurrentThread.ThreadState.HasFlag(ThreadState.Aborted))
        {
            if (!process.HasExited) continue;
            return process.ExitCode;
        }
```

The only problem with this is outputs. Weirdly, there are sometimes strings missing in the end both from output and error, and adding `Thread.Sleep` solves this problem, meaning that asynchronous writing can't keep up for some reason.

This seems like a trivial problem, yet I can't find a reliable solition. `Thread.Sleep` is hardly a good practice, and execution time is very important. What is the best way to reliably get all errors and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the output is that the write ends of the anonymous pipes used to carry it to your process may not be flushed until the process exits - it doesn't always happen, but you can't rely on it *not* happening. Instead, why not run the process stuff, including `WaitForExit()` (or maybe just `WaitForExit()`) in a separate thread? Your original thread can wait for this worker to finish in `Thread.Abort`able manner (e.g. `Thread.Join()`), and you'll have your complete output. Or, if you aren't worried about `ThreadAbortException` but need to be able to cancel the `WaitForExit()` call, you can use `WaitHandle.WaitAny(prc.Handle,cancellationToken.WaitHandle)`.

Comment: What is cancellationToken.WaitHandle here and where do I get it from?

Comment: Cancellation tokens are a managed mechanism for task cancellation. If you don't have one around, disregard that part. OTOH if you are using `Thread.Abort()` to cancel operations, you'd better read up on cancellation because aborting threads is generally considered a bad idea.